# "org.json.JSONObject" missing "Request.Method.GET" and "com.android.volley" JsonObjectRequest arguments appear to out of order

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to make a GET request for some Json data with the "com.android.volley" module's JsonObjectRequest.

The android development page (google's own website) shows the set up like this:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() { ... } );
```

The order of the arguments being: 1. Method 2. url etc etc. HOWEVER, when I try this using Android studio, I get an error and it asks for the arguments in a different order. It wants, the url 1st and the method 2nd. Shouldn't be a problem, just enter the information in a different order, but there is another problem.

It insists that the Method be of `org.json.JSONObject`, not `com.android.volley`. BUT, I can't find the `Request.Method.GET` from `org.json.JSONObject` in the auto drop-down selector in Android Stuido, and I have import `import org.json.JSONObject` in my code at the top of the page! So what the heck!? The only `Request.Method.GET` I can find is from `com.android.volley`, which doesn't seem to be accepted by the `JsonObjectRequest`. I don't know why.

My Code: (pretty much all underlined in red the way it is)

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import java.io.IOException;

      <more code here, but not relevent>

        try{

            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(getString(R.string.getAddress), Request.Method.GET, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("games");
                        JSONArray releventGames = new JSONArray();
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject game = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            String homeTeam = game.getString("hometeam");
                            String awayTeam = game.getString("awayteam");
                            if (homeTeam.contains(teamName) || awayTeam.contains(teamName)) {
                                releventGames.put(game);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
//            queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
//            JSONObjectResquest();
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.i("getGames","Failed to Get games");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I also have `implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'` in my build dependencies.
I tried 1.0.0 and 1.1.0 , neither solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

YOu have used

```
new JsonObjectRequest(getString(R.string.getAddress), Request.Method.GET, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){...});
```

when the proper form is :

```
new JsonObjectRequest(Method, url,jsonRequest,listener,errorListener);
```

or

```
new JsonObjectRequest(url,JSONObject,listener,errorListener);
```

Try this :

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "URL", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                
            }
        },null);
```